# graph to compare to series with huge difference

Tags: excel, graph

so I have this graph which has 4 legend out of which 3 are in clustered column and 1 in line lets call it 'total'(which is the total of 3 clustered column) I want to add 4th parameter which is completely different from theses 4 and has values in millions. How can add that line in this graph or is there any way other way to compare that series value with 'Total'.

[image]

I Tried pasting one chart over other but I think it will be confusing for viewer

[image]

.

Comment: Not looked at your data but factor the values *1000 or divide 1000 or 1000000 so they all scale to a sensible range on the graph.

Comment: Use a combo chart and check the box for Secondary Axis for the series that has a different scale.